# IntelliJ does not suggest to upgrade maven dependency version when there's a newer one available

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm fairly certain I've had this feature before, where IntelliJ puts a squiggly line underneath a dependency version in my pom file when there's a newer one available in maven central.

Does anyone know how to enable this, or any suggestion as to why it doesn't recognize that there's a newer version?

I've updated my repositories in build tools → Maven → repositories.

Currently running IntelliJ Ultimate 2023.3.4.

Comment: There is a plugin by Checkmarx that will display CVE info e.g. _"Dependency maven:org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.30 is vulnerable, safe version 6.1.2 CVE-2024-22233 7.5 Uncontrolled Resource Consumption vulnerability with High severity found"_ I'm not sure it will tell you if there's a newer version.

Comment: Thanks, @Mr.Polywhirl, I'll keep this in mind. However, I know there should be some IntelliJ functionality for what I'm asking for, so I'll leave the question open.

Comment: Make sure you have Package Search (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12507-package-search) and Package Checker (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18337-package-checker) installed and enabled (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/plugins-settings.html)

Comment: package checker actually seems like the plugin I want, but it's not available for IntelliJ Ultimate 2023.3.4, maybe that's it.

Comment: Package Checker comes bundled with IDEA and I don't think you can even uninstall it. Check if it is maybe disabled in your installation?

Comment: Ah, my bad, it's actually there. I have both of them, and they're both enabled. Still not working, though. But I'm fairly certain this is what I'm looking for / what I've used before, so I'll accept your answer and try to figure out why it's not working.